# Coloring a row depending on a boolean column value

Tags: angularjs, colors, row, angular-ui-grid

I use a ui-grid in an app showing some data.
The first column is a boolean value.

If this value is true I want to color the whole row green (by setting bg-success as cellclass)

How can I check for the boolean value? 
How can I change the whole row's color?

My setup is pretty basic, so I dont include code you know anyways ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you'll use `boolOdd` as the boolean and `bg-error` as other class, this would be the answer:

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-class="{'bg-success': boolOdd, 'bg-error': !boolOdd}">
<td>{{column.name}}</td>
<td>{{column.text}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I use ui-grid so I would need to do the class change based on the first column (and the columnDef). I think I would need a rowtemplate or cell class function that could retrieve the value of the first column.
If I try this with get getCellValue(row, col) there is an error when I set col = 1 (or 0). Is there any easy way to get that column value?

Answer (score 0):

Have you though about using ngClass.

Could add this on the `<tr ng-class="{'bg-success' ? yourBool }">`

Comment: How to implement the boolean term into ui-grid's Cellclass?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to try [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Could you paste sample code?